# Help with basic inequality (complex numbers)

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, complex-numbers

I want to prove

> \begin{align}
> \lvert z\rvert &\geq \Re\{z\} \tag{1}\\
> \lvert z\rvert &\geq \Im\{z\} \tag{2}
> \end{align}

I start with $z=x+iy$ so 
$$
\lvert z\rvert=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\tag{3}
$$

With the following (I guess it's valid for complex numbers?)
$$
\lvert z\rvert =\sqrt{z^2} \iff \lvert z\rvert^2 =z^2 \tag{4}
$$

I can write 
\begin{gather}
\lvert z\rvert^2=x^2+y^2 \tag{5}
\end{gather}

Using
\begin{gather}
\Re\{z\}=x \iff \Re\{z\}^2=x^2 \tag{6}
\\
\Im\{z\}=y \iff \Im\{z\}^2=y^2 \tag{7}
\end{gather}
I can now write
\begin{gather}
\lvert z \rvert ^2=\Re\{z\}^2 +\Im\{z\}^2 \tag{8}
\end{gather}

I'm stuck here.

What is the next step? Or should I stop here and conclude something from $(8)$?

Thanks!

**Update:** I not sure, but shouldn't we have absolute values in $(1)$ and $(2)$, i.e. $\lvert z\rvert \geq \lvert \Re\{z\}\rvert$
and $\lvert z\rvert \geq \lvert\Im\{z\}\rvert$?

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Since $\Im \{z\}$ is a real number, you know that $\Im \{z\}^2 \geq 0$.

Comment: Hi! Do you mean: Starting with $\lvert z \rvert ^2=\Re\{z\}^2 +\Im\{z\}^2$ we have $\lvert z \rvert ^2=(\Re\{z\}^2 +\Im\{z\}^2)\geq 0$. Therefore we kan remove $\Re\{z\}^2$ and because of this we can change the equality sign to an inequality sign, i.e. $\lvert z \rvert ^2\geq\Im\{z\}^2 \iff \lvert z \rvert \geq\Im\{z\}$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\begin{cases}\lvert z\rvert=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ge x\\\\\lvert z\rvert=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ge y\end{cases}$$

are always true.

Indeed they are true when $x,y<0$ and for $x,y\ge0$ we can square and obtain

$$\begin{cases}x^2+y^2\ge x^2\\\\x^2+y^2\ge y^2\end{cases}$$

As an alternative, note that in **polar form** the equations are equivalent to

$$\begin{cases}\rho\ge \rho \cos \theta \iff \cos \theta \le1\\\\\rho\ge \rho \sin \theta \iff\sin \theta \le1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Hi! Do you mean: we start with $x^2\geq0 \iff x^2+y^2\geq y^2$ and with $\lvert z\rvert^2 =x^2+y^2$ we have: $\lvert z\rvert ^2\geq y^2 \iff $$\lvert z\rvert \geq y$. And finally with $\Im\{z\}=y$ we have $\lvert z\rvert\geq\Im\{z\}$. Is this algebraically correct?

Comment: Let consider $\lvert z\rvert=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ge x$, I mean that when $x<0$ the inequality is always satisfied since LHS is $\ge0$; when $x\ge0$ we are allowed to square the inequality without loss of information and obtain $x^2+y^2\ge x^2\implies y^2\ge0$ whiach is always true. By the way by the polar form it is trivially true.